# how to add new item in pandas series without erasing other items

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following pandas series.

```
new_orders_list
Out[853]: 
Cluster 1    [525, 526, 533]
Cluster 2    [527, 528, 532]
Cluster 3    [519, 534, 535]
Cluster 4              [530]
Cluster 5         [529, 531]
Cluster 6    [520, 521, 524]
```

And,I have two more series which I get after some slicing on dataframe.

```
condition
Out[854]: 
5    525
Name: order_id, dtype: object

condition2
Out[855]: 
Clusters
Cluster 6    1
Name: quant_bought, dtype: int64
```

Now I want to add value of `condition` series 525 to `new_orders_list` at `Cluster 6` `(index from condition2 series)` location. And erasing off `525` from `Cluster 1` location. So, it should look like this

```
Cluster 1    [526, 533]
Cluster 2    [527, 528, 532]
Cluster 3    [519, 534, 535]
Cluster 4              [530]
Cluster 5         [529, 531]
Cluster 6    [520, 521, 524, 525]
```

I am doing following in Python. But it appends to the previously stored values.

```
new_orders_list.append(pd.Series(condition.values ,index = 
condition2.index))

Cluster 1    [525, 526, 533]
Cluster 2    [527, 528, 532]
Cluster 3    [519, 534, 535]
Cluster 4              [530]
Cluster 5         [529, 531]
Cluster 6    [520, 521, 524]
Cluster 6                525
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution.

New Series of remove data was created and was called `remseries`.

Types of values in `lists` in `Series` `new_orders_list` are integers and types of other `Series` are `strings`, so all values are converted to strings.

Then was selected rows by subsets by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and values was added and removed.

```
print new_orders_list

Clusters
Cluster 1    [525, 526, 533]
Cluster 2    [527, 528, 532]
Cluster 3    [519, 534, 535]
Cluster 4              [530]
Cluster 5         [529, 531]
Cluster 6    [520, 521, 524]
Name: no, dtype: object

print condition

5    525
Name: order_id, dtype: object

print condition2

Clusters
Cluster 6    1
Name: quant_bought, dtype: int64

#create new Series for remove
remseries = pd.Series(condition.values, index = ['Cluster 1'], name='rem')
print remseries

Cluster 1    525
Name: rem, dtype: object
```

```
#create dataframe from series
df = new_orders_list.reset_index()
print df

    Clusters               no
0  Cluster 1  [525, 526, 533]
1  Cluster 2  [527, 528, 532]
2  Cluster 3  [519, 534, 535]
3  Cluster 4            [530]
4  Cluster 5       [529, 531]
5  Cluster 6  [520, 521, 524]

#convert values in list from int to string
df['no'] = df['no'].apply(lambda x: [str(i) for i in x])

#add and remove items
df.loc[df['Clusters'].isin(condition2.index.tolist()), 'no'] = 
df['no'].apply(lambda x: x + condition.values.tolist())

df.loc[df['Clusters'].isin(remseries.index.tolist()), 'no']  = 
df['no'].apply(lambda x: [k for k in x if k != ''.join(remseries.values)])

#check types of values in list
print [ type(x) for x in df['no'][0]]

[<type 'str'>, <type 'str'>]

#convert values in list from string to int
df['no'] = df['no'].apply(lambda x: [int(i) for i in x])
```

```
print df

    Clusters                    no
0  Cluster 1            [526, 533]
1  Cluster 2       [527, 528, 532]
2  Cluster 3       [519, 534, 535]
3  Cluster 4                 [530]
4  Cluster 5            [529, 531]
5  Cluster 6  [520, 521, 524, 525]

#check types of values in list
print [ type(x) for x in df['no'][0]]

[<type 'int'>, <type 'int'>]
```